# How to get all apk files downloaded from android marcket?

Tags: android

I am implementing one application related to getting download files info.

Based on my requirement i get the downloaded files info form sdcard/download.

But i am not getting the info related to the apps download from android marcket.

Where the download apps are stored in android mobile.

And how to get the names of download apps from marcket.

If any one know the solution please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For application that download from android Market(Google Play ) and application that install in to SD card you can find application install location for them by below path.

```
mnt/asec/Application Package Name/pkg.apk
```

this will Only for Application that install to SD Card.

For application that install in to device memory you can refer below path.

```
 data/app/application packagename.apk
```

for internal application you need to get access of Root directory.
Hope this will give you hit.